# Google Drive API: 500 Internal Server Error when copying real time document

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api, google-drive-api

I can't copy real-time document using this API:

I get this even when trying https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy#try-it

Returns: `500 Internal Server Error`

Using Docs document file ID works so it's probably not supported on real time documents as Google Drive doesn't have a Make a copy.. on real time documents.

Does anyone have more info about this?

Answer (score 0):

The copy operation is not supported for realtime documents right now.  You can create a copy by using the [realtime.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/realtime/get) and [realtime.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/realtime/update) operations.

Comment: Any equivalent to this in the gapi.drive.realtime package? (using JS wrapper)

Comment: No, no reason you can't invoke this from the client though.